# My application does not display in full screen on android

Tags: android, kivy

I want to display my application on my samsung A13 phone in full screen mode. However, no matter what I do, it doesn't want to: the phone's time and navigation system remain visible. I use Buildozer on Ubuntu Mate 20.04 to compile kivy in apk file .

I have tried :

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '491')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1000')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', '1')
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'True')
```

On my pc the display is full screen, on my phone not.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '491')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1000')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', '1')
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.fullscreen = True
```

It bugs my pc and the application is not visible. On my phone no visible effect.
How to display in full screen mode my application on android?

Answer (score 1):

[solved]
I have to edit the buildozer.spec with it:

fullscreen = True